# Logging into a website by code

Tags: c#, authentication, httprequest

I have to download an excel file from a website through code. But the downloading requires logging into a website. So I am confused that what data should I post to login from code.

Here's the request from chrome:

```
Request URL:https://206.82.192.135:4100/wgcgi.cgi?action=fw_logon&style=fw_logon.xsl&fw_logon_type=status
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:884
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Cookie:domain=null; username=CandA
Host:206.82.192.135:4100
Origin:https://206.82.192.135:4100
Referer:https://206.82.192.135:4100/wgcgi.cgi?action=fw_logon&style=fw_logon.xsl&fw_logon_type=status
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
action:fw_logon
style:fw_logon.xsl
fw_logon_type:status


Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fw_username"

[username appears here]
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fw_password"

[password appears here]
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fw_domain"

Firebox-DB
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fw_domain"

Firebox-DB
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Login
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

fw_logon
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="style"

fw_logon_progress.xsl
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fw_logon_type"

logon
------WebKitFormBoundaryPAzPZF4h5AQHA6Ic--
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Length:289
Content-Type:text/xml
Date:Wed, 21 Aug 2013 13:00:10 GMT
Server:None
```

Comment: Is there any part of request payload ?
Because it contains the username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored more and found that I was not being authenticated by the SSL and I was getting this exception:
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

So I got a piece of code from
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492735/webexception-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-chann)

System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you search for a simple solution try to use the `WebBrowser` control. You can iterate through all of the items of the page and set username and password, then genaerate a click on the login button.

Comment: I tried using WebBrowser control, I post my login credentials, when I navigated to the URL, it opens a new window and continue loading and nothing happens after that.